# Having an object remember the next object of its kind

Tags: java

Right, vague as that topic might have been, let me just start by confessing that this is a homework related question. So if you have some fun vendetta against those kinds of questions, be warned.

I've been sitting with it for a good few hours though, and I'm quit embarrassed to not have "gotten it" yet.

So I was hoping some of you could show me what I'm missing.

I am to make a class, which stores a variable, and remembers the next object of that class.

The following is my main class:

```
public class SticksAndStones {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = "n";
    Stick currentStick = null;
    int numberOfSticks = 0;

    while (response.equals("n")) {

        System.out.println("What diameter should the stick have?");
        response = Integer.toString(scan.nextInt());

        currentStick = new Stick(Integer.parseInt(response), currentStick);
        numberOfSticks++;

        System.out.println("Are you done adding sticks? ('n' or 'y')");
        response = scan.next();

        while (!response.equals("y") && !response.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Please type 'y' for yes, or 'n' for no.");
            response = scan.next();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSticks; i++) {
        System.out.println(currentStick.getDiameter());
        currentStick = currentStick.getNext();
    }

}
}
```

My Stick class looks like:

```
public class Stick {

int diameter;
Stick stick;

public Stick(int diameter, Stick stick) {

    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.stick = stick;

}

public int getDiameter() {
    return diameter;
}

public Stick getNextStick() {
    return stick;
}
```

Now as you can see, my class seems able to remember the previous stick, but not the next one in any way.

The reason this is a problem, is because at the bottom of my SticksAndStones class, I try to print the diameters of each stick out, but they don't come out in the correct order. In other words, the first stick comes out last, and the last stick comes out first.

Which I don't need. I need them to come out the other way around. First stick in, as first stick out.

Our only constraints in this task is that we may not use arrays, lists, tables or databases of any form.

Am I missing something incredibly simple here?

PS: Would use the "homework" tag, but it doesn't allow it.

**UPDATE**

New SticksAndStones class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SticksAndStones {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String response = "n";
    int numberOfSticks = 0;

    Stick firstStick = null;
    Stick currentStick = null;
    ;
    Stick prevStick = null;

    while (response.equals("n")) {

        System.out.println("What diameter should the stick have?");
        response = Integer.toString(scan.nextInt());

        if (firstStick == null) {
            firstStick = new Stick(Integer.parseInt(response));
            prevStick = firstStick;
        } else {
            currentStick = new Stick(Integer.parseInt(response));
            prevStick.setNextStick(currentStick);
            prevStick = currentStick;
        }

        numberOfSticks++;

        System.out.println("Are you done adding sticks? ('n' or 'y')");
        response = scan.next();

        while (!response.equals("y") && !response.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Please type 'y' for yes, or 'n' for no.");
            response = scan.next();
        }
    }

    currentStick = firstStick;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSticks; i++) {
        System.out.println(currentStick.getDiameter());
        currentStick = currentStick.getNextStick();
    }

}
}
```

And my Sticks class:

```
public class Stick {

int diameter;
Stick stick;
Stick nextStick;

public Stick(int diameter, Stick stick) {

    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.stick = stick;

}

public Stick(int diameter) {
    this.diameter = diameter;
}

public int getDiameter() {
    return diameter;
}

public Stick getNextStick() {
    return stick;
}

public void setNextStick(Stick nextStick) {
    this.nextStick = nextStick;
}
}
```

A smile and a hug to whoever can tell me why I'm hitting a NullPointerException.

Comment: Maybe add two references?  `Stick prevStick` and `Stick nextStick`

Comment: @gtgaxiola How would that help? I'm a little slow in these things, so could you perhaps demonstrate how I could use that to make it work?

Comment: @ViRALiC lol "homework" tag is a good suggestion actually...

Comment: @Alboz Oh, it's there. I just can't use it until I have 1500 rep. Silly logic as that may be.

Comment: Does your answer have to have the sticks remembering each other? Versus using a list of sticks instead.

Comment: @RachelG. Yes. We may not use any lists of any kind in any class. Meaning you guess correctly that the user may present an unknown amount of sticks and we have to store all of them, through one remembering the other. Smart sticks.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding how an object would remember the *next* object of its class.  I know they're doing interesting things with quantum computing, but I haven't heard of predicting the future yet.

Comment: When you say not allowed to use lists, you mean you can't use `java.util.List`? Because you're basically building up a linked list without calling it that.

Comment: This definitely seems like an interesting exercise. You are writing a very specific linked list class. Hopefully you will next learn how to generalize this pattern for broader use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of refactoring goes a long way:

Since it is not possible to know a construction time what is the `next` Stick the constructor should not take that as a parameter or a least give the option to create the object with no `nextStick`

```
public Stick(int diameter) {
    this.diameter = diameter;
}
```

Before you start looping to add Sticks you keep 3 references:

```
Stick firstStick = null;
Stick currentStick;
Stick prevStick = null;
```

And inside your `while loop` after you ask for the Diameter you check if the initial stick has been defined or if you are continually adding sticks...

```
if (firstStick == null) {
    firstStick = new Stick(Integer.parseInt(response));
    prevStick = firstStick;                
} else {
    currentStick = new Stick(Integer.parseInt(response));
    prevStick.setNextStick(currentStick);
    prevStick = currentStick;
}
```

Outside your loop when you are printing the information you set your `currentStick` to point to the `firstStick` and loop as always

```
currentStick = firstStick;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSticks; i++) {
    System.out.println(currentStick.getDiameter());
    currentStick = currentStick.getNextStick();
}
```

**Update**

As per your change to the `Stick` class

This should be how it looks like

```
public class Stick {

    int diameter;
    Stick stick;

    public Stick(int diameter) {
        this.diameter = diameter;
    }

    public int getDiameter() {
        return diameter;
    }

    public Stick getNextStick() {
        return stick;
    }

    public void setNextStick(Stick stick) {
        this.stick = stick;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yours was the most helpful example, but I seem to have some problem  with it. Could you please look it over, to see if I've misunderstood anything anywhere? You're my hero.

Comment: @ViRALiC What are the inputs you are putting to get a NullPointerException?

Comment: I'm trying that last pretty loop you gave me. It seems to hit an issue, but I can't seem to tell where exactly the problem arises.

Comment: @ViRALiC it is actually your `Stick` class you have 2 Stick references.... `getNextStick` is getting `stick` but `setNextStick` is modifying `nextStick`

Comment: Oh yeah that was it! Thanks a lot mate, that did it! Totally saved my ass today!

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously no `Stick` can "remember" the next stick when it is first created, because there isn't any next stick yet.  But if the only `Stick` constructor takes the previous stick as an argument, then -- though it's pretty ugly -- it could *modify* the previous stick to have a reference to the new one:

```
public Stick(int diameter, Stick previousStick) {
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.previous = previousStick;
    previousStick.next = this;
}
```

Of course that assumes one new and one renamed field in class Stick.

It would be better form to add the forward reference *after* creating the new `Stick`, however, so that the `Stick` constructor does not modify its arguments:

```
public Stick(int diameter, Stick previousStick) {
    this.diameter = diameter;
    this.previous = previousStick;
}

// ... main() ...
    Stick newStick = new Stick(Integer.parseInt(response), currentStick);

    currentStick.setNext(newStick);
```

Moreover, if you want to be able to traverse the linked list (which is what you are creating) in the forward direction, then you need somewhere to retain a reference to the first `Stick`.  If you don't need to traverse the list backward, then you can omit tracking that reference (in which case the `Stick` constructor does not need to take a `Stick` as a parameter).  I'll leave the rest of that for you to work out.

Comment: Worrying about modifying constructor arguments is perhaps a bit retentive in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that avoids adding a second reference so each Stick remembers the previous one is to write a recursive method that does a [post-order traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order) of the stick chain:

```
public static void printSticks(Stick s) {
  if (s != null) {
    printSticks(s.getNextStick());
    System.out.println(s.getDiameter());
  }
}
```

This approach isn't appropriate for a very long list, because it's subject to a stack overflow error, but it's an example of how you can use recursive algorithms to work around limitations of a data structure that you're stuck working with.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your class know about the previous and next sticks.

```
public class Stick {
    private int diameter;
    private Stick previousStick;
    private Stick nextStick;

    public Stick(int diameter, Stick previousStick, Stick nextStick) {
        setDiameter(diameter);
        setPreviousStick(previousStick);
        setNextStick(nextStick);
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then in your main method, you would need to set them appropriately. This is where you should "do your homework". Below is some starting help. Think about how to use it.

```
Stick lastStick;
Stick currentStick;

lastStick = currentStick;
currentStick = new Stick(diameter, lastStick, null);
lastStick.setNextStick(currentStick);
```

Comment: And, barring time travel, just where is the program supposed to get the `nextStick` parameter for the constructor?

Comment: As I showed, use null and then just set it with the setter.

Comment: Why set it in the constructor if it is always `null`?

Comment: For extendability. It is fine either way. Perhaps even have two constructors where one calls the other with the null.